# PHP variables not being passed to the next page

Tags: php, variables, post

So I have two files. The first is the index.php in the root folder the other is an index.php found in a controller folder named post_link. I want to pass email, password, and action from the form in index.php of the root to the index.php of post_link but its just passing empty values when I try to get them using, filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'value'). How do I pass variables from index.php of the root to the index.php of post_link?

index.php of the root:

```
<?php 
session_start();
require_once('model/fields.php');

// Add header
include '/view/header.php';

// Add fields with optional initial message
$validate = new Validate();
$fields = $validate->getFields();
$fields->addField('first_name');
$fields->addField('last_name');
$fields->addField('password');
$fields->addField('email', 'Must be a valid email address.');

// Makes sure the pages uses a secure connection
if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) {
$url = 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
header("Location: " . $url);
exit();
}

$action = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'action');
if ($action === NULL) {
$action = 'login';
$email = '';
} else {
$action = strtolower($action);
}

if ($email == '') {
$login_message = 'Login or register if you are a new user.';
}
else {
$login_message = '<span class="error">Invalid email.</span>';
}
?>
<main>
<h2>Login</h2>
<form action="post_list" method="post" class="aligned">
<fieldset>
    <legend>Customer Login</legend>

    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="login">

    <label>Email:</label>
    <input type="text" class="text" name="email">
    <br>

    <label>Password: </label>
    <input type="text" class="text" name="password">
    <br>

    <label>&nbsp;</label>
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
    <br>
</fieldset>
</form>

<form action="." method="post" class="aligned">
<fieldset>
    <legend>Customer Registration</legend>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="reset">

    <label>You must be registered to view posts</label>
    <input type="submit" value="Register here">
</fieldset>
</form>

<p><?php echo $login_message; ?></p>
</main>
<?php include 'view/footer.php'; ?>
```

index.php of the controller:

```
<?php
    // session_start();
    require_once('../model/database.php');
    require_once('../model/customers_db.php');
    require_once('../model/validate.php');
    $action = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'action');
    if ($action === NULL) {
    $action = 'login';
    $email = '';
    } else {
    $action = strtolower($action);
    }

    switch ($action) {
    case 'login':
        $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email');
        $password = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'password');

        if (is_valid_customer_login($email)) {
            $_SESSION['is_valid_customer'] = true;
            $customer = get_customer($email);
            $first_name = $customer['firstName'];
            $last_name = $customer['lastName'];
            if (is_valid_customer_login_password($email, $password)) {
                include('../view/customer_menu.php');
            } else {
                $login_message = '<span class="error">Invalid password.</span>';
                include('../index.php');
            }

        } else {
            if ($email == '') {
                $login_message = 'Login or register if you are a new customer.';
            }
            else {
                $login_message = '<span class="error">Invalid email.</span>';
            }
        }
        break;
    case 'reset':
        // Reset values for variables
        $first_name = '';
        $last_name = '';
        $email = '';
        $password ='';

        // Load view
        include 'view/register.php';
        break;
    case 'register':
        // Copy form values to local variables
        $first_name = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'first_name'));
        $last_name = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'last_name'));
        $email = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email'));
        $password =trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password'));

        // Validate form data
        $validate->text('first_name', $first_name);
        $validate->text('last_name', $last_name);
        $validate->email('email', $email);
        $validate->password('password', $password);

        // Load appropriate view based on hasErrors
        if ($fields->hasErrors()) {
            include 'view/register.php';
        } else {
            add_customer($first_name, $last_name, $email, $password);
            include 'view/customer_menu.php';
        }
        break;
    case 'logout':
        $_SESSION = array();   // Clear all session data from memory
        session_destroy();     // Clean up the session ID
        $login_message = 'You have been logged out.';
        include('view/login.php');
        break;
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: I'm sorry I don't see how the second index.php is invoked by the first one...

Comment: oh sorry. the index.php file of the controller is located in a folder called post_link. So when the form in the index.php of the root is submitted it loads the index.php of the controller folder, post_link.

Comment: What does `$_POST['email']` give ?

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: email in C:\xampp\htdocs\market\post_list\index.php on line 2

Comment: Can you comment out all the `require_once` in the postlist/index.php file and retry the test ?

Comment: I'm getting the same error. I also tried to put $_POST['email'] as the first line of code and get the same error. Would being a secure https connection  have anything to do with passing variables?

Comment: Oops, didn't notice it... Yes, avoid **redirections**.

Comment: Is there another way to pass the email and password over a secure https connection? I wanted to pass email and password to the index.php in the post_link folder to validate if it is a registered user or not.

Comment: I reproduce your issue (my bad... since https redirections occurs in the first file, it doesn't matter). I'm searching why.

Comment: @rajankur is right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ain't gonna work this way, You have to use the action as **"post_list/index.php"**. So modify your form as:

```
<form action="post_list/index.php" method="post" class="aligned">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Customer Login</legend>
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="login">
        <label>Email:</label>
        <input type="text" class="text" name="email">
        <br />
        <label>Password: </label>
        <input type="text" class="text" name="password">
        <br>
        <label>&nbsp;</label>
        <input type="submit" value="Login">
        <br>
    </fieldset>
```

Comment: Great! that did it. I thought setting the action="post_list" would automatically load the index.php. Anyway thanks rajanku!

Comment: You should upvote the answer so that it can help others also.

Comment: Sorry i'm still new. It won't let me upvote until i have 15 reputation. Once I do I will come back and upvote you.